# Connect 1/4 inch TRS to 1/8 inch stereo input on computer?

Tags: cable, xlr

Can anyone tell me how to connect my studio monitor speakers with an XLR or 1/4 inch TRS input to my 1/8 inch stereo output on my computer sound card? I don't see any adapters or cords that convert TRS to regular unbalanced stereo. Is this is possible without a mixer?

Answer (score 2):

You can get adapters for this, but the sound will be much better if you get a sound card that has the TRS outputs, or if you use an external breakout box (USB or Firewire, USB on most PCs.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with an adapter is that you lose the features balanced outputs gives you - most importantly is the low noise floor and immunity to interference balanced cables give you.

As Neil says, get a decent sound card with balanced outputs.

Comment: Are sound cards with balanced outputs common these days or would these typically be an after market add on?

Comment: They seem to be more and more common as the prosumer market keeps growing

Comment: Still not safe to assume that a random person's laptop would be though?

Comment: A good sound card is not an internal one these days. So don't worry about the laptop - as long as you get good ASIO drivers you're sorted.